# ios 4.3 application compatibility with ios 5.0

Tags: ios4, ios5

I have developed application for iPad which is  ios 4.3, its working fine for ios 4.3. but when i checked the application with ios 5.0 my application is crashing.  is there any version compatibility issue?

please help me to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem. As some of the classes are deprecated in iOS 5

What you have to do is just find the error( i.e o which line of code the app is crashing)

then apply a version check like this

```
 float version  = [[[UIDevice currentDevice]systemVersion]floatValue];
    if(version < 5.0){
        //iOS 4 compatible code
    }else{
        //iOS 5 compatible code.
    }
```